# Copy and past data from one column to different column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to first find bank cell in colunm G and then select the cell in same from column F. Then select the data from that cell to last filled cell and copy. then again come to the blank cell of G column and paste the values. Pl help me out.

```
Sub copyy2()
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim A As Long
    Dim otherCol As Integer
    Dim cell As Excel.Range    
    sourceCol = 8   'column H has a value of 8
    otherCol = sourceCol - 1    'column before H
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    With Sheets("sheet1")
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        A = currentRow
            'cell = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol)
            Exit For
  End If
    Next  
    'A = cell.Row    
    Cells(A, otherCol).Select         
    Range(Selection, Cells(A, otherCol).End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Range(Selection, Cells(A, sourceCol)).Select
    End With        
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Do you want columns G & F or H & G? Your narrative contradicts your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
dim rng as range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    set rng = .columns("G").specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).cells(1)
    if .cells(.rows.count, "F").end(xlup).row > rng.row then
        .range(rng.offset(0, -1), .cells(.rows.count, "F").end(xlup)).copy _
           destination:=rng
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it will be best if you can provide me the full coding. I'm new in VBA. Plz..

Comment: That is the 'full coding'.

Comment: Thanks...it is working fine. But only one issue that is found is when no value is found in F column, it is coping the last value in F column. This should stop if no data available in F column.

Comment: And also it should paste value only, not the formula.